# Django Image gallery

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, image

I'm trying to make a image gallery template in Django that will pull in new images when they are added to the blog. What I'm wanting are three or four columns of thumbnail sized images in a grid.

So far my template looks like this:

```
{% for image in images %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
        <tr>
    {% endif %}
    <td>
      <a href="{{ image.get_absolute_url }}"> <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" width="304" height="236"/></a>
    </td>
    {% if forloop.last %}
        </tr>
    {% else %}
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"4" %}
            </tr><tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

However this won't allow me to manipulate the images as easily as I would like - I was hoping to use Bootstraps columns but each time I try that it gives me the images in a single column.

Comment: Are you after something like [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the following for 3 column grid?

> (change col-md-4 to col-md-3 for 4 columns)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    {% for image in images %}
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="{{ image.get_absolute_url }}"> <img src="{{ 
image.image.url }}" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" width="304" height="236"/>
          </a>
       </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works pretty well the formatting is a little messy at the moment but I think I can clean it up a bit with CSS.